# Deal aggregator iframe tracking

Tags: iframe, aggregator

I noticed a deal aggregator site (specifically onespout.com) uses an iframe to show the site where you are actually getting the deal from.  This means you are on the aggregator's site the entire time.  I was wondering how you the aggregator site can interact with that iframe so you know when a purchase is complete and such.  I know this is a little vague but thanks in advance.